# Computing $\det\left(\binom{i+j}{i}\right)_{1\le i,j \le n}$

Tags: matrices, binomial-coefficients, determinant

I have trouble computing the determinant  $\det\left(\binom{i+j}{i}\right)_{1\le i,j \le n}$ , although i tried another variant of the same determinant : $\det\left(\binom{i+j}{i}\right)_{0\le i,j \le n}$ and managed to compute this one (it is $1$).

I know the answer must be $n+1$, but i'm really stuck on how to prove it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just checking, you mean an $n\times n$ matrix $A$  where $A_{ij}=$ $ {i+j}\choose{i}$?

Comment: Let $x_j=j$. Them you need to compute $\det\left(\binom{x_j+i}{i}\right)_{i,j=1}^{n}$. Try to add some rows to get the Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: @Alan, yes i mean the determinant of the matrix ${i+j}\choose{ i}$ where $1\le i, j\le 
 n$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218441/determinant-of-a-pascal-matrix-sort-of

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determinant of a Pascal Matrix, sort of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218441/determinant-of-a-pascal-matrix-sort-of)